# AWS CDK -- How do I retrieve my NS Records from my newly created Hosted Zone by AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, aws-cdk

Say I created a public hosted zone or fetch a hosted zone from lookup and I want to retrieve the NS Records for other usage

```
const zone = new route53.PublicHostedZone(this, domain + 'HostedZone', {
    zoneName: '' + domain
})
```

```
const zone = HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'HostedZone', { domainName: config.zoneName });
```

Does the current CDK have any methods to do that. I've look around the API doco and found none. Any suggestions?

---

### Update

I did try the `hostedZoneNameServers` property. However, it doesn't seem to return anything.

```
const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'DotnetHostedZone', {
      domainName: <myDomain>,
    });

    new CfnOutput(this, `output1`, {
      value: zone.zoneName
    });

    new CfnOutput(this, `output2`, {
      value: zone.hostedZoneId
    });

    new CfnOutput(this, 'output3', {
      value: zone.hostedZoneNameServers?.toString() || 'No NameServer'
    });
```

```
 ✅  test-ops

Outputs:
test-ops.output1 = <myDomain>
test-ops.output2 = <myZoneId>
test-ops.output3 = No NameServer
```

And I confirm with my zone and used  to do a record export, I can retrieve all my records.

**The ultimate goal is to automate a subdomain provisioning. But I'm currently scratching my head on this route.**

Answer (score 2):

There is a `hostedZoneNameServers` property on the zone object.

```
const zone = HostedZone.fromLookup(this, 'HostedZone', { domainName: config.zoneName });
const nsRecords = zone.hostedZoneNameServers;
```

Reference:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/aws-route53/hostedzone.html#aws_route53_HostedZone_hostedZoneNameServers

Comment: Sorry If I spam your notification. I did try with hostedZoneNameServers property but it returns me nothing at the moment. And I can confirm the records are there when I retrieve them with my zone id. I've done a update on my description.

Comment: thanks, my only thought is that in the documentation it means that `hostedZoneNameServers` can be null if the zone is private or if the zone is imported... perhaps the `fromLookup` results in a null value but the original ` new route53.PublicHostedZone` result may have this property set.  Is it possible to try and check and use the value of `hostedZoneNameServers` from when the zone is initially created?

Comment: I did double check my zone, it came back with correct domainName etc from my fresh creation. And my records are not imported. They are created by the `cdk` itself. Some of these little gaps here and there kinda make it hard to go fully automation like Terraform can do.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to automate subdomain provisioning with the following code.  Note that these hosted zones share the same stack, which may not work for your use case.

```
export const hostedZone = new HostedZone(stack, `${env}-hosted-zone`, {
  zoneName: host,
})

// API
const apiHost = `api.${host}`
export const apiHostedZone = new HostedZone(stack, `${env}-hosted-zone-api`, {
  zoneName: apiHost,
})
// note that this record is actually on the parent zone, 
export const apiHostedZoneNsRecord = new NsRecord(stack, `${env}-hosted-zone-ns-api`, {authoritatively pointing to its sub-subdomain
  recordName: apiHost,
  values: apiHostedZone.hostedZoneNameServers as string[],
  zone: hostedZone,
})
```

This resulted in the following snippet of CFT (${env} and ${rnd} replaced with concrete values, of course):

```
"ResourceRecords": {
 "Fn::GetAtt": [
  "${env}hostedzoneapi${rnd}",
  "NameServers"
 ]
},
```

If you can accept the same stack constraint, you should be able to accomplish this.  Note that while I could accept the constraint for this stack, more broadly I have a multi-account structure and had to manually add the sub-account's subdomain NS record to the parent account's root domain.  Summary of this setup:

```
root account:
  example.com
    NS child.example.com // manually added
child account:
  child.example.com // contents of `host` below 
    NS api.child.example.com
  api.child.example.com //  automatic subdomain created with code above
```

Comment: I found this answer to be correct.

For me specifically, I was getting the odd error of "Expression expected.  ts(1109)"

and the subtle difference was adding the "as string[]" which solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe you can do that right from the script. The values will be just "Tokens" which will be replaced by CloudFormation after/during the deployment, but not at during synthesis. Outputting during synthesis will therefore leave you blind. You will need to fetch them in a `post-process` I guess..

I am running into the same issue, which is why I found your post :D

Answer (score 0):

`hostedZoneNameServers` is not defined for private or imported zones as mentioned in [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.PublicHostedZone.html#hostedzonenameservers). You can use only if you create your zone in CDK (e.g. `new PublicHostedZone(...).hostedZoneNameServers`).

If you create the zone elsewhere, try to use AWS Route53 [GetHostedZone API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_GetHostedZone.html).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
    const nsRecords = hostedZone.hostedZoneNameServers;

    if (nsRecords) {
      for (let i=0; i<4; i++) {
        context.cfnOutput(this, `NS Record${i+1}`, Fn.select(i, nsRecords));
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@JD D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806763/jd-d) mentioned, there is a `hostedZoneNameServers` attribute on hosted zones, but they aren't available in cross stack. The documentation has been updated(or this was missed when first answered) to reflect this.

[CDK V1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-route53.HostedZone.html#hostedzonenameservers) /
[CDK V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53.HostedZone.html#hostedzonenameservers)

> hostedZoneNameServers?
> Type: string[] (optional)
>
> Returns the set of name servers for the specific hosted zone. For example: ns1.example.com.
>
> **This attribute will be undefined for private hosted zones or hosted zones imported from another stack.**

So in order to accomplish what you want, you will need to set the NS values as an output on the stack that created the hosted zone and consume them by referencing the stack that provides the NS output.